# If $-1 < y -5 < 1$, is the following statement about y true: $y < 6$.

Tags: inequality

This question is from Thomas' *Calculus*. It is question (4) (d) from chapter 1.1. I'm confused about the answer in the back, which is the opposite of my answer.

The answer in the back says it is true. The reasoning in the textbook gives the following:

> $-1 < y - 5 < 1 \Rightarrow 4 < y < 6 \Rightarrow y < 6$

Before I looked at the answer, I had said it wasn't true. My reason was that $y < 6$ includes elements outside the set in the antecedent, e.g. the number $3$, as $y < 6$ implies (-$\infty$, 6). While the set in the question ranges from $(4, 6)$. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put into set-theoretic terms, $-1<y-5<1$ means that $y-5\in(-1,1),$ from which it follows that $y\in(4,6).$ Since $(4,6)\subseteq(-\infty,6),$ it follows that $y\in(-\infty,6),$ and so $y<6.$

Now, we can't go the other way in general, since $(4,6)\subsetneq(-\infty,6),$ but the implication above certainly holds.

Answer (score 2):

It is logic.  The statement is "if $4<y$ and $y<6$, then $y<6$."  It is like the statement "if it is raining, and today is Thursday, then today is Thursday."  It is obviously true.  You are throwing information away, but in logic that is OK.